# How to write the block matrix in LaTex?

Tags: amsmath

I wish to write the following block matrix in LaTex.

[image]

I have been trying a bunch of stuff, but none of it seems to work. In particular, I tried the following:

```latex
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1&        &         &          &        & 0    &         &       &         &\\
1 & 0 &        &         &          &        &      &         &       &         &\\
  &   & \cdot  &         &          &        &      &         &       &         &\\
  &   &        & \cdot   &          &        &      &         &       &         &\\
  &   &        &         & \cdot    &        &      &         &       &         &\\
  &   &        &         &          & 0      & 1    &         &       &         &\\
  &   &        &         &          &-1      & 0    &         &       &         &\\
  &   &        &         &          &        &      & \cdot  &        &        &\\
  &   &        &         &          &        &      &         & \cdot &        &  \\ 
  &   &        &         &          &        &      &         &        &  \cdot & \\
0 &   &        &         &          &        &      &         &        &         &  0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
```

But this is pretty ugly and so any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps

```
$\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right] &  &  &  &  & 0\\
 & \ddots\\
 &  & \left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right]\\
 &  &  & 0\\
 &  &  &  & \ddots\\
0 &  &  &  &  & 0
\end{array}\right)$
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

Just for the fun of it! `:-)`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\newcommand{\lr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\rr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\;
\begin{array}{@{}*{10}{c}@{}}
\cline{1-2}
\lr{0} & \rr{1} &&&&&&&& \raisebox{-1em}[0pt][0pt]{$0$}\\
\lr{-1} & \rr{0} \\
\cline{1-2}
&& \ddots \\
\cline{4-5}
&&& \lr{0} & \rr{1} \\
&&& \lr{-1} & \rr{0} \\
\cline{4-5}
&&&&& 0 \\[-1ex]
&&&&&& \ddots \\
&&&&&&& 0 \\[-1ex]
&&&&&&&& \ddots \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{0} &&&&&&&& 0
\end{array}
\;\;
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You guys are the best!

Comment: @model_checker I'm certainly not the best. Here is world excellence.

Comment: I am sorry! Last I checked there was an objection to your answer. But it's also great!

Comment: @model_checker Don't worry. I have put two `&` in addition. :-) but now it is correct.

Answer (score 8):

Here there is my proposal as the original picture using `\bmatx` command that replace a boxed matrix.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\bmatx}{\boxed{\begin{matrix} 0&  1  \\ -1&  0\end{matrix}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\, \bmatx&  &  &  &  & & & 0 \\ 
 &  \ddots&  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  \bmatx &  &  & & \\ 
 &  &  &  \ddots&  & &\\ 
 &  &  &  & 0 & &\\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  & \ddots\\ 
0 &  &  &  &  &  & & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

The best code is provided thanks to the precious comment of @Bernard.

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't add an empty 3rd column in the definition  of `\bmatx`\

Comment: Your comment not is an opinion :-) ...it is truly correct. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution. It uses a `pmatrix` environment for the overall matrix and a custom macro called `\blockmat` for the 2x2 inner matrices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\newcommand\blockmat{%
   \begin{array}{|@{\,}rr@{\,}|}
     \hline 0 & 1^{\mathstrut} \\ -1 & 0 \\ \hline
   \end{array}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\blockmat &        &           &   &        & 0 \\
          & \ddots &           &   &        &   \\
          &        & \blockmat &   &        &   \\
          &        &           & 0 &        &   \\
          &        &           &   & \ddots &   \\
0         &        &           &   &        & 0 \\  
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using Ti*k*Z that will work in all kinds of context, not just matrices, to draw boxes. You just need to put `\tl` in the point where the top-right corner is supposed to be and `\br` where the bottom-right will be. You can also use any Ti*k*Z feature to modify your box. Obviously this needs to be fine tuned depending on what exactly you're using it for (spacing etc.).

```
\newcounter{textbox}
\def\tl{\stepcounter{textbox}\tikzmarknode{a\thetextbox}{\strut}}
\def\br{\tikzmarknode{b\thetextbox}{\strut}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\draw (a\thetextbox.north west) rectangle (b\thetextbox.south east);\end{tikzpicture}}
```

The spacing in this version is not optimized for matrices, but you can use

```
\tikzmarknode{b\thetextbox}{\strut}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\draw ($(a\thetextbox.north west)+(-0.4\arraycolsep,0ex)$) rectangle ($(b\thetextbox.south east)+(0.4\arraycolsep,0ex)$);\end{tikzpicture}
```

to add extra space.

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\newcounter{textbox}
\def\tl{\stepcounter{textbox}\tikzmarknode{a\thetextbox}{\strut}}
\def\br{\tikzmarknode{b\thetextbox}{\strut}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\draw (a\thetextbox.north west) rectangle (b\thetextbox.south east);\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\tl0    &-1     &        &         &          &        &      &         &       &    0    \\
1       & 0\br  &        &         &          &        &      &         &       &         \\
        &       & \cdot  &         &          &        &      &         &       &         \\
        &       &        & \cdot   &          &        &      &         &       &         \\
        &       &        &         & \cdot    &        &      &         &       &         \\
        &       &        &         &          &\tl0    & 1    &         &       &         \\
        &       &        &         &          &-1      & 0\br &         &       &         \\
        &       &        &         &          &        &      & \cdot   &       &         \\
        &       &        &         &          &        &      &         & \cdot &         \\ 
0       &       &        &         &          &        &      &         &       &  \cdot  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```